# validating bootstrap modal in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

im working with laravel And i have bootstrap modal i want to become required the fields. i tried this one `required` in my input tag and textarea and its not working . i tried to validate in the fields in controller but it wont work i know there something wrong in what im doing. im just beginner in laravel. help me out

this is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header info-color white-text">
        <h4 class="title">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> New Message</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <label for="defaultFormEmailModalEx">Recipient</label>
      <input type="email" name="recipient" id="defaultFormEmailModalEx" class="form-control form-control-sm"  autocomplete="off" v-model="recipient">
      <br>
      <label for="defaultFormMessageModalEx">Your message</label>
      <textarea type="text" name="newmessage" id="defaultFormMessageModalEx" class="md-textarea form-control" v-model="newMessage"></textarea>
      <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-2">
          <button class="btn btn-info" @click="sendNewMessage">Send
              <i class="fa fa-send ml-2"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this what `@click="sendNewMessage"` do

```
sendNewMessage(){
  axios.post('http://localhost/sendnewmsg', {
        recipient: this.recipient,
        newMessage: this.newMessage
      })
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        /*if(response.status===200){
          app.messages = response.data;
          app.privateMsg = response.data;
        }*/

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  this.recipient='';
  this.newMessage='';
},
```

and this is the controller i think here must be put the validation

```
public function sendnewmessage(Request $request){
  $recipient = $request->recipient;
  $newmessage = $request->newMessage;

  $checkUser = DB::table('users')->where('email','=', $recipient)->get();
  if($checkUser->isEmpty()){
    echo 'data doesnt exist';
  }
  else{
    echo 'data exist';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass [manual validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators) in your **`sendnewmessage`** function,
Please check the below code.

```
public function sendnewmessage(Request $request){

$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'recipient' => 'required',
                'newMessage' => 'required',
             ]);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
}

$recipient = $request->recipient;
$newmessage = $request->newMessage;

$checkUser = DB::table('users')->where('email','=', $recipient)->get();
if($checkUser->isEmpty()){
    echo 'data doesnt exist';
}
else {
    echo 'data exist';
}
}
```

And if you want to show **errors** on your modal you can write this  in your modal

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Hope this will help you comment if  you have any query.

Comment: have you used my code `return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);` ?

Comment: i have the varable errors and i can see it in my console but i cant display it in view

Comment: ok..i think you haven't used form inside your bootstrap modal that is the problem.

Comment: okay where i need to put the error inside of the form or outside? i put a form and it closes the modal why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168524/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-rookie).

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you want...

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'recipient' => 'required',
    'newmessage' => 'required',
]);
```

[Here is validate document for laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)

And to show error messages in js you can get erros and store it in a variable

```
let $errors = response.responseJSON;
```

Comment: Well you just stored it in a variable you can easily loop it through a foreach and append it to the form or whatever you prefer more

Comment: By the way you are using ajax and you are trying to show error messages in php thats not possible, you should foreach it with js...